# Is there a cost for submitting an application to the AppStore?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, developer-program

I already own my developer programmer account for which I paid the $99 per annum.

I understand that it allows me to develop and test on the device(s) and to submit applications to the Store.

However, I wonder if there is another associated cost on the submission of the application, and per application.

I am also aware that the process could be rather long, so I am also asking, if, for any reason the application is rejected, are there any fees or cost related to re-submission.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Questions about programming, development, and listing your apps on the App Store are off topic for Ask Different. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: Hello. I don't think this question is about any of those issues, not programming nor listing my apps nor about development. I am simply asking if there is any fee on the app submission. Look at this question, which was also closed in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123555/how-much-time-does-it-take-for-an-app-to-be-available-in-the-app-store. In one, I ask how much it costs, in the other I ask how much it takes. But they were both closed. So, this way I wouldnt be able to ask it anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: Hello. This is a question about listing your app on the app store (submission is part of that process). Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not about submitting my app. I am questioning if there is a cost on submitting an app. And forgive me, but I don't see anything in FAQ about "listing apps in the App Store". Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: A question about whether there is a cost to submit an app is a question about submitting an app. It's even in the title. The FAQs say that this is off-topic at the very top: "...and it is not about... Apple Developer Programs or iTunes Connect." [iTunes Connect](http://developer.apple.com/support/resources/itunes-connect.html) includes the process of submitting your app. I'm sorry to close your question, but it is off topic for this site.

Comment: Very well, I was unaware that iTunes Connect was the way to do it. But then, this is a group of questions that can't be answered anywhere in SE. I don't understand why these issues cannot be discussed and therefore don't see the value for the 'developer-program' tag, I see some questions with this tag that could have been closed and weren't. Well, I am sorry and thanks for your time, I'll head for meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as your USD99 annual membership fee for Mac Developer Program is current (and you don't break the Agreement or any NDA), that paid membership already covers the following typical software distribution costs:

- set up your App ID for distributing your app
- set up and download credentials needed to sign the app for distribution via the App Store.
- keeping your tax information and deducting the appropriate withholding on apps sold for selected countries' App Store.
- review of your app
- hosting of your app (at App Store)

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Submission for review and ultimately the hosting on the App Store are all included in your developer subscription.